# Vim character insert slows exponentially on Centos 6 when :syntax on

Tags: vim, syntax, centos

We upgraded some servers from CentOS 5 to CentOS 6. On all the CentOS 6 servers, Vim (same bug on vim 7.2 and 7.3) often runs normally for a few hours, but inevitably begins inserting characters very slowly.

At first it merely takes a second or two for the characters I type to appear, but once the slowness is apparent, the time taken per character increases exponentially. After typing a dozen or so characters it is in practice impossible to insert any more. You can still insert one character at a time by typing a character, then typing `Ctrl-c`, after which the character you typed will appear. Non-insert mode still works fine.

Setting `fdm=manual` has no effect. The problem occurs only with source code files over about 100K. I edit only Perl source code files at work. It does not go away on exiting and re-starting vim, but always goes away by the next day, to reappear after a few hours of work.

Setting `:syntax off` solves the problem! But then I get no syntax highlighting.

Vim still works fine on the same files from machines running CentOS 5. No other software has this problem.
Has anyone else seen similar behavior? Any ideas or solutions for it?

Comment: I've had performance issues with vim automatically trying to establish an X connection, and slowing down that way; to get around this, I aliased vim to `/usr/bin/vim -X`. I don't know if this is your problem, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: @Barton - This also happens with non-gui vim in a terminal. Also, if it were X, turning syntax off wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Actually, this didn't have anything to do with gvim. I think that it may have been an issue with using vim on ssh with X forwarding though. I missed the part about turning syntax off.

Answer (score 1):

Vim syntax highlighting is defined in a series of .vim files, typically under vimXX/syntax, where XX is the version of vim. These files contain regular expressions which define syntax highlighting classes (e.g. 'comment' or 'flow control'). I'm guessing that the slow-down is caused by a run-away regular expression. It's possible that CentOS 6 modified syntax/perl.vim in such a way that adding individual characters may cause a combinatorial explosion somewhere inside the regex engine.

You could try replacing syntax/perl.vim with the same file in CentOS 5, and see if the problem persists.